# Can anyone send keys to this input field with selenium ? (Selenium Detected)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, detection

I am just trying to send keys to #inputPlaylist text field in this website https://youtubemultidownloader.net/playlists.html, but selenium is detected in someway.

I tried the most famous driver arguments and JS scripts but in vain.

Can anyone handle this website ?

Answer (score 0):

@Othman Alkhatib, I tried the following and it is working. Let me know if this is what you were looking for. The last line `time.sleep(5)` is kept just so that anyone running this can see what is happening before the browser gets closed:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_options = Options()
s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, service=s)
driver.get("https://youtubemultidownloader.net/playlists.html")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "inputPlaylist").send_keys("ABC")
time.sleep(5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you are right, website doesn't give me error when I send "ABC", it stops me when I send a playlist url, and exactly when I send any letter after list parameter like this url **"https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=P"**   ........  

and there is another question about this website, how can a text appear on the screen but when I do inspect I can not find it, (I'm talking about the textarea in this website when I input playlist url manually)

Comment: I have attached the error I am getting in my response. Is the same error you are talking about?

Comment: yes exactly....

Comment: I am getting the same error through manual entry of url also.

Comment: I have no problem with manual entry, but anyway, if you solve this problem tell me how me please, I need it necessary.